# Why doesn't this code show the "reached out of memory" error here?

Tags: c, bus-error

I tried to reach out of the array's memory in my compare function. To my surprise, it works, however, I think there should be a memory error. Could someone have a look and give me an answer?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int string_compare(const char* w1, const char* w2, unsigned int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(w1[i] != w2[i]){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    printf("%d\n",string_compare("Hello'\0' world!", "Hello",10));
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, not a memory error. C has no built-in bounds checking, it just goes off the rails and anything can happen, including nothing at all.

Comment: It's called undefined behavior.  But essentially what's happening is that you are comparing bytes of memory that don't belong to your program code, could contain anything, not guaranteed to be null terminated, and could change any moment.

Comment: [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) can result in a memory error, but there is no such guarantee. Undefined behavior means that anything can happen, which includes the possibility of the program working as intended.

Comment: There is no UB here: Compare stops at `'` != `'\0'`.  At index 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works, while I think there should be a memory error.

There is no memory error.

Compare stops at index since `w1[5] != w2[5]` is true.  `w1[5]` is a `'`, not a *null character*.

---

Perhaps OP wanted to compare `"Hello\0 world!", "Hello"`?

Now that will have trouble with `index`6, which is beyond `"Hello"` and incurs undefined behavior.  "It works," might happen,  might fail,  It is UB.

---

A proper string compare would stop when character differ or a *null character* is detected.

```
// if(w1[i] != w2[i]){
if(w1[i] != w2[i] || w1[i] == 0){
```